# Retag windows-7-x64 to windows-7 and 64-bit?

Tags: support, status-completed, retag-request

Probably, but since there are already 12 questions tagged [windows-7-x64](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/windows-7-x64), I figure I should ask first.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

*What's next?* [windows-7-professional-x64]

I also think we should just retag [windows-7-x64] as [windows-7] and [64-bit]...

---

Let's suppose it's tagged [windows-7-x64], it won't show up under the tag [windows-7] or [64 bit]. *Bad...*

Should all those questions be retagged to [windows-7-x64] and force users to type that? *That's wrong...*

Comment: Either I'm misinterpreting your answer or you're contradicting yourself...

Comment: He's just agreeing with you

Comment: @heavyd: Correct. Just clarifying why we should get rid of the tag...

Comment: I agree, I'd separate the elements of the tag.